# Expected a ';' in an array declaration

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_BIT 64

struct binario_puro {
    char bit[MAX_BIT];
} binario_puro;

int main() 
{
    binario_puro numeri[] = {
        {"010"}, {"111"}, {"000"}, {"00"}
    };

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting compile-time error: expected ';' at `numeri[]`, how can I fix?

If I replace `binario_puro` with `int` it compiles.

Comment: `struct binario_puro` => `typedef struct binario_puro`

Comment: `clang` says "must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'binario_puro'".

Comment: you should make use of compiler feedback. It should tell you about these things

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem, where you're declaring a `struct` and also a variable inadvertently:

```c
struct binario_puro {
    char bit[MAX_BIT];
} binario_puro;
```

This does not declare an alias, it creates a variable called `binario_puro` which is not useful here.

What you mean is:

```c
typedef struct binario_puro {
    char bit[MAX_BIT];
} binario_puro;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct binario_puro numeri[] = {
            {"010"}, {"111"}, {"000"}, {"00"}
        };
```

don't forget that `struct` keyword